# Markdown - Github Is there way to make it interactive?

Tags: github, markdown

Currently I'm writing a README.md file for a project and I'm wondering if is there anyway to add some interactions with it.

Something like:

[image]

Does git hub support it?

If so, is there any example?

Comment: https://markdownlivepreview.com/ first google result for "markdown live"

Comment: I've edited the question, I wasn't clear. Would be nice to see this in github